# Ubuntu 18.04 shutdown problem on Gigabyte Z390 - AMD Radeon RX 580

Tags: shutdown, ubuntu-gnome

After a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04.3 (UEFI mode) on my system (Gigabyte Z390 Designare - Intel i9-9900K - Sapphire AMD Radeon RX 580), turning off the system, either through the terminal or with the graphic interface, the screen turns black but the RGB lights of the motherboard and the fans stay on for a time sometimes very long before turning off. Most of the discussions read about this concern similar problems arising from nvidia graphics cards and can be solved by installing proprietary drivers but are not applicable in my case. What might this problem depend on and how could I try to solve it?

Comment: Report it as a bug to Launchpad and/or try the latest kernel.